# Is there a way as client,on ubuntu in a local network, to view/gain access to a linux partition(while the server is on windows 10)?

Tags: networking, dual-boot, server, partitioning

Heys guys,
I'm trying to make it simple to understand,please be patient if it's confusing:

I have two pcs on my network,one is a notebook with ubuntu
and the other one is a desktop with dual-boot(windows 10 and deepin)
My question is,if I can gain access to my deepin partition,through my ubuntu laptop,when the desktop pc is running windows at that moment

Comment: This would require the deepin partition to be accessible to Windows 10. If this is the case, you can share the deepin partition via samba and it can then be accessed by ubuntu. If Windows cannot see the partition, it can also not share it.

Comment: thanks!No,Windows cannot see the Linux partition

Comment: @Bruni Theoretically you *could* export it as a iSCSI target, and mount that on Ubuntu... Not sure that would count as a good idea, tho.